# In Android App,I Need Pdfviewer Jar For Viewing pdf,AnyOne Can Help me?

Tags: java, android, pdf

Here,I Open Pdf From Raw Folder,,,And Use Jar Of PDfViewer,But Problem Is..Viewing Of Pdf..I want to open with big size,and its open in small size..
uripdf = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                        + R.raw.knowhindi;

```
            final Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(uripdf), "pdf/*");
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Second.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: please explain.. if you need a pdf library then check my answer.

Comment: post your Second.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MuPdf Library is a better option;

http://mupdf.com/docs/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android

Comment: jar library ?. please explain what is your need..?

Comment: Already I use pdfviewer jar file ..but Problem Is viewing of pdf..Its Size is very small...And I want Pdf with big size...so where i change in jar..?with pdfviewer.

Comment: thanks have u any jar file of pdf?so i can solve my prob

Comment: you cant view large pdf in your application.?

Comment: try to implement with mupdf its very fast.or install the mupdf application in your phone.

Comment: means??mupdf is also viewing large..so y its not possible??means..i have jst size prob

Comment: actually u are calling an intent to open your pdf file in your phones default pdf viewer.

Comment: can u do me a favor. please tell me what u app is meant for.

Comment: i calling a pdf for my app from raw folder..for security..and i use jar file..of pdfviewier

Comment: Viewing is very small..i m newer in stackoverflow..tel me how to load my snapshot..here??

Comment: hey can i use mupdf with raw folder??if yes dan how its possible??

Comment: I Run my app with sd card but my requirement is open pdf from raw or assest folder

Comment: I successfullly Created App For Pdf Viewer With Mupdf Thanks For My help